# php form writing to text file - prevent POST redirect re-submission

Tags: php, forms

The code below is a php form that writes to a txt file and outputs the results on the same page.

However when I refresh the page POST data is automatically added again - and I want to prevent this. I understand I should redirect users to another page, but how do I do that if my results are on the same page and I want them to stay on the same page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <title>Score Watch</title>
 </head>
<body>
 <p>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
 <label>Date: &nbsp;
<input name="date" class="datepicker" id="date" required type="text"
data-hint="" value="<?php echo date('d/m/Y'); ?>" />
 </label>
 <br>
 <label>Score:
 <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
 </label>
  <label>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
 </label>
 </form>
  </p>
 <?php
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "$date $name<br>" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    echo $posts;
 ?>
</body>
 </html>
```

I've seen the `header('Location')` tactic, but I can't use it since i output data on the same page?

Comment: save the data on session, or pass it via get method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ADD THIS TO TOP OF YOU PAGE**

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['name'],$_POST['date'])){
    // Text we want to add
    $posts = "{$_POST['date']} {$_POST['name']}<br>";

    // Add data to top of the file
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts . file_get_contents('posts.txt') );

    // Redirect user to same page
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
?>
```

**Change your body a little bit**
Replace this:

```
<?php
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "$date $name<br>" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    echo $posts;
?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
    // Print contents of posts.txt
    echo file_get_contents("posts.txt");
?>
```

Comment: Lastly, how would I modify my code so the latest data submission appears at the top of the output? Not one after the other. I need to reverse the order data is outputed, with the latest submission at the top.

Comment: I think perhaps something to do with 'file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts, FILE_APPEND);'

Comment: Yes I modified the code hours ago, now the latest submission should be on first line of the file.

`file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts . file_get_contents('posts.txt') );`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same page, if you don't want to use another page. The data should be transmitted either via GET or SESSION

To prevent cyclic redirection, you should put in condition your redirection.

I would suggest:

At the top of the page

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

then

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['date'])) {
    $date = $_POST["date"];
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $posts = file_get_contents("posts.txt");
    $posts = "$date $name<br>" . $posts;
    file_put_contents("posts.txt", $posts);
    $_SESSION['posts'] = $posts;
    header("Location: samepage.php?success=1");
}
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['success'], $_SESSION['posts'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['posts']
}
?>
```

The redirection also should be before the HTML, to prevent sent headers issue.

Only the last block can be printed inside the `<p>`'s because it's actual output.